# Good practise - private event vs private method in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, methods, private

Is it considered "good practise" to have a private event that will only be subscribed to from within the Object itself? (a WPF-Window)?

The alternative would be to just call a Method similar to the EventHandler delegate wherever I invoke the event.

With an event it would look something like this:

```
    private delegate void ZoomScaleChangedEventhandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    private event ZoomScaleChangedEventhandler ZoomScaleChanged;

    ...        
    this.ZoomScaleChanded += this.ZoomScaleChangedHandler;
    ...

    private void someMethod()
    {
        // Change zoom scale
        this.ZoomScaleChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void ZoomScaleChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

With the method like this:

```
    private void someMethod()
    {
        // Change zoom scale
        this.ZoomScaleChanged();
    }

    private void ZoomScaleChanged()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229011(v=vs.100)) help you?

Comment: In general events are meant to notify subscribing objects of an event. Since you are using it in the object itself, you must ask yourself: is this suited for an event or should I just call the method directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it considered "good practise" to have a private event that will only be subscribed to from within the Object itself?

No. It doesn't make much sense to define a private event just to be able to notify (call) some private methods. Then you might as well call these methods directly instead of raising an event.

Events are used to signal the occurrence of an action to the outside world and an event sender doesn't generally know which object or method that will handle the events it raises.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you.